# Update extents in QGIS 3 layer?

Tags: qgis, dxf

I have imported a DXF file into QGIS 3 and it displays fine but I want to change the extents to a different location. The Layer Properties/Update Extents does nothing if I pick it:

[image]

Comment: You probably need to reproject your data if you want to move it.

Comment: How do you reproject my data? I just exported it from Adobe Illustrator. I assume you are talking about adding spatial data to the file somehow?

Comment: At present your data is just a collection of random numbers (essentially) - only when combined with a projection do they have a meaning as points on the ground.

Comment: Right so how do I combine it with a projection? It looks like the only way I can find is to hand edit the project.qgs file from [here]:(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270745/how-do-i-update-the-extent-of-a-raster-in-qgis-to-the-actual-extent)

Comment: I did some research and figured out I can use the "Reproject Layer" from the Toolbox to reproject the layer created from the DXF file to use the EPSG-4326 - WGS-84 projection. I then went to the Layer Styles to change the layer extents but they do not change the location of the polygons on the map:

Comment: Here is the dialog to change the location of the polygons on the map shown [here](https://unpluggedsystems.com/qgis-screen-shot.jpg)